# What is the purpose of using a PublishSubject to trigger a disconnect rather than just unsubscribing from a Subscription in RxAndroid?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, rx-android, rxandroidble

I'm working on a bluetooth project that uses RxAndroidBle for bluetooth communication. I came across two different ways that the subscriptions are cleaned up. I was wondering if anyone could explain the differences and benefits of each if there are any. The two examples are as follows.

First: using a `PublishSubject` to trigger a disconnect with the bluetooth device

Code Sample: https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/polidea/rxandroidble/sample/example4_characteristic/CharacteristicOperationExampleActivity.java

Second: disconnecting with the bluetooth device by unsubscribing from the `Subscription`

Code Sample:
https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/polidea/rxandroidble/sample/example2_connection/ConnectionExampleActivity.java

My main focus is on the `triggerDisconnect()` methods in each of the examples. In what ways is the `PublishSubject` way different from just keeping a reference to the `Subscription` and then unsubscribing?

I do apologize for how open ended this question is but I'm not sure how better to explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [PublishSubject](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html) `disconnectTriggerSubject` help construct `connectionObservable` using this `prepareConnectionObservable()` method earlier. Then act as a proxy to pass `null` to `onNext()` method of the observable.

Then inside `onNext()` of this subscription:

```
.subscribe(
      characteristic -> {
           updateUI(characteristic);
           Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Hey, connection has been established!");
      },
      this::onConnectionFailure,
      this::onConnectionFinished
);
```

the `updateUI(characteristic)` method is get called with `null` value.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. The `.takeUntil(disconnectTriggerSubject)` is the key to understanding the `disconnectTriggerSubject`. `takeUntil()` means that items emitted from the connection observable (after subscribing of course) will be emitted until an item is emitted from `disconnectTriggerSubject`. Since `disconnectTriggerSubject` is a `PublishSubject` it is both an observer and observable. Due to it being an observable it can emit items through the `onNext()` method. So, calling `disconnectTriggerSubject.onNext(null)` causes `takeUntil(disconnectTriggerSubject)` to execute, which prevents any new items from the `connectionObservable` to be emitted. This is essentially the same as unsubscribe since it "Stops the receipt of notifications on the Subscriber that was registered when this Subscription was received." http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Subscription.html

Comment: Can use something else in place of disconnectTriggerSubject to trigger takeUntil?